# Single page javascript application - page and page transition management

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've been using jQuery mobile a lot recently and I really like the mechanism they have for managing pages (or views) in a single page application. jQuery mobile handles the hiding and showing of the various views and the page transitions between views.

So you define a page like so:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> BLAH ... </div>
```

and then you can easily navigate and transition to that page using a href:

```
<a href="#home" data-icon="arrow-r">home</a>
```

Or they have various JavaScript methods to achieve the same thing:

```
$.mobile.navigate("#home");
```

Is there a JavaScript library out there that is designed specifically to handle pages/views in a similar way?

Comment: jQuery Mobile page transition is inspired by [jQTouch](http://jqtjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Angular JS is a SPA goddess. (Single Page Application)

Comment: Give more details, elaborate on your answer.